# Access static variable in symfony 2.2 twig

Tags: static, twig, symfony-2.2

I have a class containing constant options in array form:

```
namespace MyNameSpace;

class OptionConstants
{
  /**
   * Gender options
   */
   public static $GENDER = array(
    'Male',
    'Female'
   );

  /**
   * University year levels
   */
   public static $UNVERSITY_STANDING = array(
    '--None--',
    'First Year',
    'Second Year',
    'Third Year',
    'Fourth Year',
    'Graduate Student',
    'Graduated',
    'Other'
   );
}
```

How can I access $UNVERSITY_STANDING or $GENDER in symfony 2.2 twig?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My Solution for a problem like this is to create a static member in the TwigExtention:

```
class TwigExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    private static $myStatic = 1;
    ...
```

Create a Funktion in the Extention:

```
public function getStatic($something)
{
    self::$myStatic += 1;
    return self::$myStatic;
}
```

And call this in the twig:

```
{{"something"|getStatic}}
```

Greetings

Answer (score 15):

[just call constant function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/constant.html)

```
{{ constant('Namespace\\Classname::CONSTANT_NAME') }}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Anyway, I have used your suggested way in accessing constant variables. However, it still does not work for accessing static variables.

Answer (score 9):

You can create a custom Twig function as below:

```
$staticFunc = new \Twig_SimpleFunction('static', function ($class, $property) {
        if (property_exists($class, $property)) {
            return $class::$$property;
        }
        return null;
    });
```

Then add it into Twig

```
$twig->addFunction($staticFunc);
```

Now you can call this function from your view

```
{{ static('YourNameSpace\\ClassName', 'VARIABLE_NAME') }}
```